# conditional statement in DB2 without a procedure

Tags: db2

I need to execute statements conditionally in DB2. I searched for DB2 documentation and though **if..then..elseif** will serves the purpose. But can't i use **if** without a procedure.?

My DB2 verion is 9.7.6.

My requirement is I have a table say Group(name,gp_id). And I have another table Group_attr(gp_id,value,elem_id). We can ignore ant the elem_id for the requirement now.

-> I need to check the Group if it have a specific name.

-> If it has then nothing to be done.

-> If it doesn't have I need to add it to the Group. Then I need to insert corresponding rows in the Group_attr. Assume the value and elem_id are static.

Comment: Without a procedure, the SQL is non-procedural, but if you provide more detail there may be a way. Are you familiar with the CASE...END expression ?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: Also please post the version of DB2 you're using and release of DB2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for the conditional insert. For the scenario that I mentioned, the solution can be like this.

```
Insert into Group(name) select 'Name1' from sysibm.sysdummy1 where (select count(*) from Group where name='Name1')=0

Insert into Group_attr(gp_id,value,elem_id) select g.gp_id,'value1','elem1' Group g,group_attr ga where ga.gp_id=g.gp_id and (select count(*) from Group_attr Ga1 where Ga.gp_id=g.gp_id)=0
-- In my case Group_attr will contain some data for sure if the group has exists already
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an anonymous block for PL/SQL or a compound statement for SQL PL code.

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
   FOR ROW AS
     SELECT PK, C1, DISCRETIZE(C1) AS D FROM SOURCE
   DO
     IF ROW.D IS NULL THEN
       INSERT INTO EXCEPT VALUES(ROW.PK, ROW.C1);
     ELSE
       INSERT INTO TARGET VALUES(ROW.PK, ROW.D);
     END IF;
   END FOR;
 END
```

Compound statements :

- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004240.html
- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/c0053781.html
- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0004239.html

Anonymous block :

- http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053848.html
- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0908anonymousblocks/

Many ot this features come since version 9.7